# Trigger Jquery Modal From Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I'm trying to trigger a jquery modal box from javascript but I don't know how. I'm doing a form verification to check if an item is filled or not, which shows a message on screen to say it needs to be filled. This part works fine but I'd also like to use the jqueryui I'm using on the site to fire off a modal box saying something similar.

Anyone got any pointers how to combine the two? I know JQuery is a javascript library so I hope I'm not making a total spanner out of myself and it's really simple....

Thanks all!

### JavaScript form verification

```
<script>
function validateForm()
{
var e = document.getElementById("Consultant");
var x = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
if (x==null || x=="")
  {
  document.getElementById("EC1").style.display = "block";
 <-- code to fire off a modal box here -->
  return false;
  }
}
</script>
```

### JQuery Modal

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $("#dialog").dialog({
            bgiframe: true,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                Ok: function() {
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                }
            }
        });
    });
    </script>

<div id="dialog" title="Form Error!">
    <p>
        Please fill out all items and try again
    </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this : `$('#dialog').dialog('open');`

[jQuery API Documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#method-open)

And better yet, why not use jQuery to validate your form?

Your code :

```
function validateForm() {
   var e = document.getElementById("Consultant");
   var x = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
   if (x==null || x=="") {
      document.getElementById("EC1").style.display = "block";
      <-- code to fire off a modal box here -->
      return false;
   }
}
```

Becomes :

```
function validateForm() {
   var e = $('#Consultant');
   var x = e.val();

   if (x == null || x == "") {
      $('#EC1').hide();
      $('#dialog').dialog('open');
      return false;
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks - I've just tried this and it only seems to work after a page refresh. So the message on screen gets shown but no modal box, refresh the page and the modal box appears.

Comment: @BenWilliams Something else must be wrong with your page, could you supply the HTML? And possibly a JSFiddle to demonstrate the issue you mentioned?

Comment: Thanks again for the help... I've managed to get the modal box and verification working fine the only issue I now have is that when the form loads it shows the modal box too. will that be an issue with my dialog settings posted above? I tried CSS disply:none but it still showed.

Comment: ...I tried to add it to jfiddle and it looked a complete mess! haha. I'll try again...

Comment: @BenWilliams Yes, by default the Dialog opens when it is first initialized, to solve this add the property `autoOpen: false`. http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-autoOpen

Comment: Wow! Amazingly awesome - all working fine. Thank you very much for your help!